# why is the regex function always popping up the Attribute Error?

Tags: python, regex, attributeerror

I have been writing a function in python to get the IP of a computer. The code is given below :

```
    def getip(self):

            self.path = "/root"
            self.iplist = []
            os.chdir(self.path)
            os.system("ifconfig > ipfinder")
            try:

                    file = open("ipfinder","r")
                    self.pattern = '(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}'
                    while True:
                            line = file.readline()
                            try:

                                    ip = re.search(self.pattern, line).group()
                                    self.iplist.append(ip)
                            except AttributeError:
                                    pass

                    file.close()

            except  EOFError:
                    for ip in self.iplist:
                            print ip
```

I know this is not a good way to get the IP of a machine. The problem is that the AttributeError pops up every single time. Why is it happening? why can't a match be found?

Comment: Have you tried a raw string for that pattern? `self.pattern = r'(\...`.

Comment: yes. Still no use.

Comment: You'll get an AttributeError for all lines that don't match the pattern. The code works for the lines that do contain an IP address.

Comment: well the error shouldn't pop up on every single line right? but that is the only thing happening.

Answer (score 1):

I ran it in my local. Found 4 things be be modified!

a) regex:- \d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}

b) trim for any extra space while reading:- file.readline().strip()

c) If it comes to end of line, break the while:-

```
if line == '':
    break
```

d) Instead of re.search, do re.finall

The modified code that works in my system without AttributeError is:-

def getip(self):

```
    self.path = "/root"
    self.iplist = []
    os.chdir(self.path)
    os.system("ifconfig > ipfinder")
    try:

            file = open("ipfinder","r")
            self.pattern = '\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}'
            while True:
                    line = file.readline().strip()
                    if line == '':
                        break
                    try:

                            ip = re.findall(self.pattern, line)
                            self.iplist.append(ip)
                    except AttributeError:
                            pass

            file.close()

    except  EOFError:
            for ip in self.iplist:
                    print ip
```

Comment: It helped solve the Attribute error issue but i still I didn't get the output yet. the last two lines didn't got executed.

Comment: Did you replace search with findall? It should work! Search won't return the matching ip, it checks if pattern matches!

Comment: unfortunately it does not. I even tried copy pasting the code (sometimes it works when i do so!!!). hopeless

Comment: I think i just found the problems. if line == '' : break . this is one issue. second issue is the pattern. you accidentally forgot  "\" before "."  .those are the only issues. Anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: cool.. :) You can modify and update these 2 entities in my answer. It would be helpful for other when they refer in the future! :)

Comment: I don't think count is needed to be introduced, coz readine will read the whole line, then goes to next ip in next line and so on. And line == ' ' is working fine too. this is not double quote, rather 2 single quotes!